In snowflake can you pass ILIKE ANY a list from a variable
When I have a list of values in one variable you can pass them to a where clause using something like this:
SET LIST = '["LIST1","LIST2"]';

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FILTER IN (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON($LIST))))

I would like to do the same thing using ILIKE ANY but it only allows you to return one row from the selection
SET LIST = '["%LIST1%","%LIST2%"]';
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FILTER ILIKE ANY (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON($LIST))))

Error: Single-row subquery returns more than one row.
So I need some way of flattening the list further but still allowing it to be passed to the ILIKE ANY() function.
The end result would be the below but using the variable $LIST
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FILTER ILIKE ANY('%LIST1%','%LIST2%')


You are looking for ARRAY_CONTAINS, the first value is the single looked for value, which needs to be of type VARIANT, thus the cast below, and the second is the VARIANT ARRAY, which PARSE_JSON produces for us.
SET LIST = '["LIST1","LIST2"]';


with example_data as (
    select * from values
    (1,'LIST1'),
    (2,'LIST2'),
    (3,'LIST3')
)
SELECT * 
FROM example_data as d
WHERE array_contains(d.column2::variant, PARSE_JSON($LIST));




COLUMN1
COLUMN2




1
LIST1


2
LIST2



For non-exact matches, we can we do the suggestion on the page, and turn the array to a string and use a REGEXP function to match. The trick is to turn the array of matches into the REGEXP:
with example_data as (
    select * from values
    (1,'ZZLIST1XX'),
    (2,'ZZLIST2YY'),
    (3,'ZZLIST3WW')
)
SELECT * 
    ,array_to_string(PARSE_JSON($LIST), '|') as a
    ,REGEXP_COUNT(column2, a) as rc
    ,rc > 0 as to_keep
FROM example_data as d




COLUMN1
COLUMN2
A
RC
TO_KEEP




1
ZZLIST1XX
LIST1|LIST2
1
TRUE


2
ZZLIST2YY
LIST1|LIST2
1
TRUE


3
ZZLIST3WW
LIST1|LIST2
0
FALSE



Thus:
SELECT * 
FROM example_data as d
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(column2, array_to_string(PARSE_JSON($LIST), '|')) > 0


This is useful buy my data is more like this:
with example_data as (
select * from values
(1,'XXLIST1XX'),
(2,'XXLIST2XX'),
(3,'XXLIST3XX')
)

Fair point, it is not always possible to know which part of a behavour one is seeking, until  you see the answer will not meet your needs.

you can transform an array to table and can join it with table using contains function to compare the value from an array with value in your table.
set list = '["LIST1","LIST2"]';

-- using inner join 
with sample_dataset(id, item) as 
(
    select * from values
    (1,'LIST1'), (2,'LIST2'), (3,'LIST3'), (4,'ITEMLIST2')
)
select dataset.* 
from sample_dataset dataset
inner join table(flatten(parse_json($list))) filter
    on contains(upper(dataset.item), upper(filter.value))
;

-- using exists
with sample_dataset(id, item) as 
(
    select * from values
    (1,'LIST1'), (2,'LIST2'), (3,'LIST3'), (4,'ITEMLIST2')
)
select dataset.* 
from sample_dataset dataset
where exists(select 1 from table(flatten(parse_json($list))) filter 
            where contains(upper(dataset.item), upper(filter.value)))
;

-- one more way
with sample_dataset(id, item) as 
(
    select * from values
    (1,'LIST1'), (2,'LIST2'), (3,'LIST3'), (4,'ITEMLIST2')
)
select dataset.* 
from sample_dataset dataset
, table(flatten(parse_json($list))) filter 
where contains(upper(dataset.item), upper(filter.value))
;

